# How do I install a mod pack on my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods, hosting, minecraft-forge

I want to install my custom mod pack that I made on Curse Forge on my own server. I host the server on my own PC and I gave the server 10 GB of RAM. It's a Forge server, and it's set up correctly I think. But when I try and export the mod pack from Curse Forge it becomes a zip file. I tried just putting the zip into the mods folder, but it only loaded 4 mods while there should be 210. I checked if the mod pack didn't export correctly but when I put it back in Curse Forge it worked fine. I then tried exporting the mods, but I don't know from which folder since there are a lot. Can somebody please help me?